# How to compute the center of mass of many images without a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, image-processing, scipy, average

I have 100 images of 10 x 10. I want to put them in a single array of shape 100 x 10 x 10 and then compute the center of mass of the 100 images in one go (without a loop for).

Currently, I am using the function `center_of_mass` from `scipy` as below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import center_of_mass

# Example data
image = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
images = np.repeat([image],100, axis=0)

result = []
for i in range(images.shape[0]): 
    result.append( center_of_mass(images[i,:]) )
```

Is there a way to remove that for loop?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: @TomRobinson - Because my actual images are larger and also I have about one million of them. Then, I feel that for loop may be speeding down my code.

Comment: “my actual images are larger and also I have about one million of them.” Why take them in memory all at the same time then? Did you write code that uses a loop and use a profiler to determine that this is the slow part that needs to be sped up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `labels` and `index` arguments to the `center_of_mass` function (one label per image). The downside is that the memory usage is roughly doubled.

```
labels = np.ones_like(images).cumsum(0)
result2 = [tup[1:] for tup in
           center_of_mass(images, labels, index=np.arange(1, images.shape[0]+1))
]

assert result2 == result
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reshape matrix and dot product.
By example:

```
import numpy as np
# Example data
image = np.arange(80).reshape(8,10)
images = np.repeat([image],90, axis=0)
images_row=images.reshape((90, 8*10))
S=np.sum(images_row, axis=1)
Y_mat,X_mat = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(8))

Y_mats = np.repeat([Y_mat],90, axis=0)
Y_mats = Y_mats.reshape((90, 8*10))

X_mats= np.repeat([X_mat],90, axis=0)
X_mats = X_mats.reshape((90, 8*10))

#center of mass:
X_c=np.dot(images_row, X_mats.T)/S
Y_c=np.dot(images_row, Y_mats.T)/S
```